# Select "underclass" and change attributes with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

First, I want to apologize for the word "underclass", but I don´t know how it´s named and I will edit the question, when I do.

My class looks like this:

```
.progressbar li {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', serif;  
    width: 12.5%;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #555555;
}
```

And I try to change the *width* attribute with jQuery like this:

```
$('li.progressbar').css('width', '16.6%');
```

or

```
$('.progressbar li').css('width', '16.6%');
```

I tried some other variations, but none of them worked. Can you please tell me how to select this class correctly?

Comment: A few name things: what you are talking about (`.progressbar li`) is a selector, both in CSS and in jQuery. The class portion is `.progressbar`. In total your selector says "select all of the `li` elements that are descendants of elements with the class `progressbar`. Your second attempt should have affected the same elements as your CSS selector, so there is likely something else going on in your CSS that is causing it not to work.

Comment: Aha, okay. Thank you